# How I can separate data and signature from pkcs7 in C++?

Tags: c++, cryptography, pkcs#7

So the question is above.

I have PKCS7 attached signature file and I have to separate them to two files: signature and original content.
I have to use C++ CryptoAPI.

I think probably I can use some of CryptQueryObject, CryptMsgGetParam, CertFindCertificateInStore functions. But maybe someone can provide code example?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try [CryptMsgOpenToDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.